# Where can I find free authoritative images of different species of Lagomorphs?

Tags: imaging

I would like to make an infographic showcasing the order Lagomorpha (rabbits, hares, and pikas), which contains a dozen genera and about 100 species. I want to include a picture for most species, or, failing that, a picture for each genus. The difficulty is that I'm not at all an expert on these animals -- I just find them cute and I like infographics -- so if I simply google around for pictures of them, I won't be able to verify that a picture labeled "Bunolagus monticularis" is actually a picture of a Bunolagus monticularis specimen, rather than something else.

Photographs would be ideal, but I'm fine with using sketches instead when no photographs are available. It would also be ideal if the images were free to use and in the public domain (or licensed under some version of Creative Commons)

Is there any source for images of species specimens that is generally considered trustworthy? It's fine if it's limited to lagomorphs, but if it also extends to other animals/plants, that's all the better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia is good for this,
The licence is what you want, and many people will have checked the animal ID.

look up the two pika species, and the rest are under

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leporidae

Comment: Good answer. I actually just finished another project like this (an infographic about foxes) using Wikipedia for images, and although I'm also not an expert on foxes, I did sort of have the feeling that it was probably trustworthy. I'll come back and accept this answer in a couple of days if there isn't a better one by then.